# SLS, Salt Package, Installing express with npm

Tags: npm, package, node-modules, salt-stack

I need to install a module "express" from npm via salt-stack.
For this, I used the following script:

```
npm-installed:
pkg.installed:
  - name: npm

npm-express-installed:
  npm.installed:
    - user: root
    - pkgs: "express"
    - dir: /opt/MyService
    - require:
      - pkg: npm
```

The installation ran successfully but on my destination I can only see

```
/opt/MyService/node_modules# ls
e  p  r  s  x
```

Is someone else here who installed npm packages via salt-stack? How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
npm-installed:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: npm

npm-packages-installed:
  npm.installed:
    - names:
      - express
      - body-parser
    - user: root
    - dir: /opt/MyService
    - require:
      - pkg: npm
```